# Android - Googlemaps - Polyline not shown

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to build up a path from a point to another in a GoogleMap, but my polyline sometimes is not shown(or drawn) by my Android project.
It happens specially when the distance START-END points is very high.
Is just the distance the problem?
Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> points;
    // Traversing through all the routes
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        points = new ArrayList<>();
        lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

        // Fetching i-th route
        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

        // Fetching all the points in i-th route
        for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
            HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            points.add(position);
        }

        // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
        lineOptions.addAll(points);
        lineOptions.width(10);
        lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

        Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

    }

    // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
    if(lineOptions != null) {
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
    else {
        Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One issue seen is on each iteration of the "traversing through.." loop you create a new `lineOptions`.  But you use `lineOptions` only outside the loop at the end.  So this means if the `result` has more than one entry you'll only draw one route - the last one.

So either (a) move the drawing of the polyLine inside of loop or (b) create `lineOptions` only once before loop.

Also, as is, you can also eliminate the creation of `points` every iteration by moving it before loop and then issue `.clear()` on the list.

So the following code assumes (a) you want to draw the polyLine for each route (based on the comment 'Drawing polyline ...for the i-th route'):

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
       ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
      // Traversing through all the routes
      for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
          points.clear();
          lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

          // Fetching i-th route
          List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

          // Fetching all the points in i-th route
          for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
              HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

              double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
              double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
              LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

              points.add(position);
          }

          // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
          lineOptions.addAll(points);
          lineOptions.width(10);
          lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

          Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

          // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
          if(lineOptions != null) {
              mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
          }
          else {
              Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
          }

      }

  }
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thank u for your suggestion, but the problem remains: sometimes it is shown the route, sometimes not; some other times the route takes even 40 seconds to be drawn.

Comment: Do you have a sense of how many points - parsing is always a performance issue but it'd have to be 1000s to add up.

Comment: Sometimes it isn't shown even if the 2 markers are closed.

Comment: sometimes it is shown even a 1000Kms route, sometimes it isn't shown a 45Kms one.

Comment: The code looks good so it all seems to "point" to the actual data - maybe log a sampling of the "path" and post an example when it does not work as expected - hard to proceed without seeing the data.